# Using Python to create a script that gives the user the next prime number in sequence and asks if they want another

Tags: python

I am trying to write a short python script that gives the user a prime number starting with 3 and continues providing the next prime number if the user wishes to see it.

Here is the function I have created. When I run it I cannot move past the number 3 which is where it starts by design. I get the print statement "3 is not a prime number" and then the input() field pops up to which I enter 'Yes' and I expect the variable 'count' to be incremented to 4 and the script to check again if it is prime.

It should go through this process checking every number and returning just the primes, then asking the user if they wish to see another one. Any ideas why I am stuck on and endless loop of "3 is not a prime number"

```
def prime_number():
    game_on = True
    
    
    while True:
    
        count = 3
    
        for num in range(2,count):
            if count % num == 0:
                print(f'{count} is not a prime number')
                break
                
            elif count % num != 0:
                print(f'{count} is a prime number')
                break
            else:
                pass
        question = input("Would you like to see another prime number?? Please enter Yes or No: ")
        if question == "Yes":
            count += 1
        
        else:
            
            break
        game_on = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def prime_number():
    game_on = True
    count = 3
    while True:
        for num in range(2, count):
            if (count % num) == 0:
                print(count,"is not a prime number")
                break
        else:
            print(count,"is a prime number")
        question = input("Would you like to see another prime number?? Please enter Yes or No: ")
        if question == "Yes":
            count = count + 1
            continue
        return
```

This solution works well. You could in fact used `int(count/2)` since no number has a factor greater than itself divided by 2.

Comment: That worked pretty well thanks. I was thinking there needed to be an explicit statement setting the state to False in order to get out of the while loop. How is this not the case? As in how does the loop know to stop when the user types 'No'?

Comment: The loop doesn't stop if the user types no, it stops if the user doesn't type 'Yes', since it's in a while loop the continue statement restarts the loop there and doesn't reach the return. You can remove the `game_on` variable, I simply assumed you were using this for something else. Glad to hear it works for you though, you can accept this answer by ticking the tick and up-vote it. It helps other users find valid answers first!

Comment: Thanks I've ticked the answer but don't have enough reputation to up-vote unfortunately. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

You should put the starting count value outside of the main loop.

```
count = 3
while True:
    for num in range(2,count):
```

Comment: I still do not understand how is he getting 3 is NOT a prime number.

Comment: The current program logic will not correctly identify prime numbers. But the question was only about why the counter did not increment. Luca's answer can be used to correct the prime number generator.

Comment: Yes. I believe it was typo. I just wanted to ensure that I was not missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that checks whether a number is a prime number

```
     1  def is_prime(num):
     2      for i in range(2,num):
     3          if num%i != 0:
     4              return False
     5      return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the "count = 3" line inside the for loop, so count will just equal 3 for every iteration. The solution would be to declare count before the While loop

```
game_on = True 
count = 3
while True:
...
```